# Subscribe delegates to all methods of a class

Tags: c#

I have just familiarized myself a little bit with C# delegates. One can subscribe multiple delegate instances to a delegate by the "+=" operator. But is it also possible to have a controller class that has delegates for all the methods in second class, and have the methods being added automatically, i.e. without having to add (or even know) each method individually to the corrsponding delegate ?

In simplified code (omitting access modifiers etc.):

```
class Car
{
    void Start();
    void Drive();
}

// I would like to have the following class generated automatically
// without needing to repeat all the methods of Car, i.e.
// without declaring a delegate instance for each of them
class CarController
{
    delegate void DoSomething();

    DoSomething StartAll;
    DoSomething DriveAll;

    void Subscribe(Car anotherCar)
    {
        StartAll += anotherCar.Start;
        DriveAll += anotherCar.Drive;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Rawling's solution is the one that I like best. It's simple and clear. As a little tweak I have tried how the thing would work with dynamically typed objects, and it works indeed: complete decoupling between Controller and controlled objects. Of course such usage of "dynamic" is not of everyone's taste...

```
public class CallAller2 : HashSet<dynamic>
{
    public void CallAll(Action<dynamic> action)
    {
        foreach (dynamic t in this)
        {
            try {action(t);} catch (RuntimeBinderException) {};
        }
    }
}

class Bike
{
    void Drive();
}

CallAller2 ca = new CallAller2();
ca.Add(new Car());
ca.Add(new Bike());
ca.CallAll(c => c.Start());  // is ignored by Bike which does not implement it  
ca.CallAll(c => c.Drive());
```

Comment: It sounds like you're describing your idea for a *solution* to a problem - a problem you've *not* told us about. We're more likely to produce good answers if you can articulate the *problem* rather than the "solution".

Comment: I guess so. As long as the signatures match with the delegate, everything should work. Did you try it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The problem I have is that I have a data model (a tree) which has to be synchronized with two different views (a standard TreeView and my custom SceneGraph). When one of the views changes, the data have to be updated, and when the data is manipulated directly in code, the views shall be updated. And even in the future I might want to have an undo manager or scripting engine relying on the same interface. Probably I'm thinking too complicated when I want to do it like shown above, but I want to separate all the different data structures as much as possible.

Comment: Particular case in the question would be good oportunity to use interface that `Car` implements and controller would just have list of cars...

Comment: @Alexei: but then again I would be responsible for calling all the Cars' methods from the CarController's method. First this is repetitive, and second this makes the controller dependent on the Car definition. If I change Car (like add another method), I have to change CarController as well.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to call methods yourself on all `ICar` in the collection - is it good or bad is your call (it does not make code much longer and give control on exceptions/termination). I also don't see how adding method to implementation class causes users of an interface to change they behavior, even adding method to interface generally not reuire changes from callers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I realise this is just essentially recreating the much-maligned `List<T>.ForEach`. Why not just use that, since it's there?

---

Although it doesn't give you the ability to just call `.StartAll` or `.DriveAll`, you could do something as simple as

```
class CallAller<T> : HashSet<T>
{
    public void CallAll(Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T t in this)
        {
            action(t);
        }
    }
}

var ca = new CallAller<Car>();
ca.Add(myFirstCar);
ca.Add(mySecondCar);

// Call a simple function
ca.CallAll(c => c.Start());

// Call a function taking parameters
ca.CallAll(c => c.SetRadio(88.1, RadioType.FM));

// Get return values... if you really need to.
Dictionary<Car, int> returnValues = new Dictionary<Car, int>();
ca.CallAll(c => returnValues.Add(c, c.GetNumberOfTyres()));
```

If you want something with actual methods to call and Intellisense, you'll need to look into code generation - it's possible, but I doubt it'd be worth the hassle.

Comment: The List<T>.ForEach seems very nice, but can it only accept Actions with one param ? (as opposed to the simple example in my OP I would like to have methods with several arguments as well). Moreover you can only pass static method to ForEach, don't you ?

Comment: As to your CallAller example - there seems to be something missing after CallAll(Expression...)... or do we need the Expression overload at all (I am not lambda expert yet) ?

Comment: @user2118609 Good spot, I changed the method signature and missed the original when I cut/pasted! I'll fix that and also put in an example with more parameters...

Comment: Upon thinking twice, I realize that I don't need Actions with several arguments because the arguments are already supplied by the caller ! The only unknown is the object that is acted on. PS: okay, I see you have been faster.. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, Rawling. I've tested it and your solution does everything I need. The use of a lambda expression is tolerable. I have still added a little tweak in my original post for those who like "dynamic".

Comment: I'm glad it's `tolerable` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

//Edit: Don't simplify the MethodInfo mi1 = mi, otherwise you get a problem called Access to modified closure

```
    static IList<Action> getDelegatesFromObject(Object obj)
    {
        Type type = obj.GetType();

        List<Action> Actions = new List<Action>();
        foreach (MethodInfo mi in type.GetMethods())
        {
            MethodInfo mi1 = mi;

            Actions.Add(
                () => mi1.Invoke(obj, new object[] {})
            );
        }

        return Actions;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to go into the direction I want. However this also gives me methods inherited from Object (ToString, Equals). Do you know how I can restrict it to my custom methods ?

Comment: I think you have to filter by methodname. The closest thing you could filter by mi1.IsVirtual, only GetType is not virtual.

Comment: Unfortunately if I filter by method names, I have to know them in the controller which is the kind of coupling I intended to avoid in the first place... :-)